# Is error due to sensor tolerance random or systematic?

Tags: sensor, error, tolerance

Welcome all. It might sound like basic question however it is question worth asking.

Comment: Wouldn't that depend on sensor? Can you be more specific?

Comment: For instance, having Hall effect component ACS712 with 1.5% output error. After calibrating sensor with precise current in fixed position. Does it mean that reading next time current is pushed can be +/- 1.5% different? Or is 1.5% error spread due to production tolerances and it is “fixed” for each individual device? Therefore, after ideal calibration in ideal conditions (no temp drift, perfect alignment, stable voltage supply ect.) sensor would always read same value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at ACS712 datasheet you see there's loosely specified a substantial noise in the output signal. That noise should be considered as random error which cannot be eliminated by  keeping the environment stable, calibrating nor straightening the pre-measured nonlinearity in software .

But its effect to the measurement accuracy can be reduced by filtering. The device has an RC filter with external capacitor. The AD-converted signal can be filtered also in the computer. The datasheet doesn't seem to provide enough statistical info for advanced mathematicians who could develop optimal software filterings. But fortunately the datasheet gives a curve how much noise causes peak to peak output variation with different inserted capacitors.

The answer to your original question is: Error is based on several mechanisms. Those mechanisms which make noise aren't systematic. Filtering can reduce noise-like errors but optimal filtering and what can be achieved depend on noise statistics. Proper filtering design needs academic level knowledge and statistical data of the noise as a stochastic process.